# How to get a php partially dynamic id of an element

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I've created different divs with partially dynamic id using php.
So I'll have:

```
<?php
 $idItem = 0;
?>



<div id="item-<?php echo ++$idItem ?>">
```

This will write an incremented id everytime.
Now i'm having trouble trying to get this id trying to use Javascript, Jquery or php.
I tried this method but it didn't work:

```
function getId(){
  var IdPhp = '<?php echo $idItem ?>';
  var IdComplete = "item-" + IdPhp;
  var idDynamic = document.getElementById(IdComplete);

if (idDynamic) {
  alert("The element id is: " + idDynamic.id);
} else {
  alert("No dynamic element found");
 }
}
```

My goal is to click on a button and copy (or append) the selected div inside another div, so when i click on the button related to the second item it will copy the second div and so on.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: You said you tried it and it didn't work -- can you clarify which part of it didn't work? Did this part of the json at least come out as expected? `var IdPhp = '<?php echo $idItem ?>';`

Comment: Is this code in a loop? You can't have multiple `getId()` functions, so each iteration of the loop redefines the function, and the final version will just have the last value of `$idItem`.

Comment: I'm afraid the issue you have is PHP can't be dynamic. PHP prints into the page only once when you load it. You'll need to rely on JS for this

Comment: When you select a DIV, add a class to it. Then when you click on the button, select the element with that class.

Comment: if you are generating unique id attributes using PHP, you are probably doing something wrong. Better to use a class and a data attribute.

Comment: @tola right! so the code is working since i get an undefined.
So would it be better if i add this item on a database in which i set their id and increment them on the server side and then get them and put them inside a container div?

Answer (score 0):

Use This Function To randomize a special ID:

```
function randName($n) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1);
        $randomString .= $characters[$index];
    }

    return $randomString;
}
```

and push the value to an array for example:

```
$array = array();
array_push($array, randName(5)); // 5 is the length of the Id
```